# Ember: load models without waiting

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is it possible in Ember to load multiple models wihtout waiting for the promise to resolve and still use the afterModel hook? Currently, my code looks like this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      imports: this.store.findAll('import', {
        skip: 0,
        limit: 5
      }),

      latestimport: this.store.find('import', 'latest')
    });
  },

  afterModel(model) {
    ...some modifications here...
  }
}
```

due to the use of Ember.RSVP, the page load waits for all promises to resolve before it renders. Can I make the page render before the models are loaded? Can I then still use the afterModel hook? My point is, the data being loaded is just side information. I don't want the whole rendering process to be blocked because of that. I did not find any information in the documentation on that, although I get the feeling that the documentation is not complete at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use following approach:

```
setupController(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model);

  Ember.RSVP.hash({
    imports: this.store.findAll('import', {
      skip: 0,
      limit: 5
    }),

    latestimport: this.store.find('import', 'latest')
  }).then(results => {
    // ...some modifications here...
    controller.set('model', results);
  });
}
```

1. It shouldn't block rendering.
2. You can still apply modifications to data.
3. You can still access data in template as `model.imports`, `model.latestimport`.

Answer (score 1):

instead of wrapping your code with `Ember.RSVP.hash` just pass hash object as it is

```
 model() {
    return {
      imports: this.store.findAll('import', {
        skip: 0,
        limit: 5
      }),

      latestimport: this.store.find('import', 'latest')
    })
  },

setupController(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model);
  // model.latestimport.then(...)
  // model.imports.then(...)
}
```